# Progress notification for old android version

Tags: android, android-notifications

I try to create a progress notification like [this example](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html). 
Here is my code:

```
 NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.download_title))
    .setContentText(getString(R.string.downloading))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

The notification worked fine, but when I want to update the progress, there is nothing happen, it only shows the notification text.

```
public void onRequestProgressUpdate(RequestProgress progress) {             
    mBuilder.setProgress(size, (int)(progress.getProgress() / size), false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

My app use the android support library `android-support-v4.jar` and set min Sdk Version is api 7. I want to show progress notification for all android version from api level 7.
Is it only works for new version? Do I have to create a custom view for notification?

Comment: @Yume117 he is using NotificationCompat ... but as it's stated in doc `On platform versions that don't offer expanded notifications, methods that depend on expanded notifications have no effect` ... so R4j, yes, you have to use custom view.

Comment: My bad.. :/ anyway good answer Selvin

Comment: @Selvin Ok, I got it. Could you answer my question with a sample or tutorial link for custom notification then I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "NotificationCompat" instead of "Notification" class. Try something like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_someicon)
  .setTicker("some title")
  .setOngoing(true)
  .setContentTitle("some content description title")
  .setContentText("some content description description");
Notification not = builder.build();

startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
```